# symfony2でconfig.ymlなどの設定をテンプレートで取得する方法

Tags: php, symfony2

config.ymlのparametersに設定した値をcontrollerで取得するには$this->container->getParameter()で取得できるのはわかっているのですが、テンプレートで直接取得することはできないのでしょうか？

symfony.1系だと、sfConfig::get('sf_category')などで取得できたと思うのですが、似たようなことができれば方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

テンプレート(Twig)でparameter等を取得したい場合、自分でtwigのglobal変数に登録する必要があります。

英語ですが、この辺りが参考になります。
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html

もしくは自作のTwigExtensionを作成し
http://docs.symfony.gr.jp/symfony2/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

getGlobals()メソッドを実装するという方法もあります。
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id1

parameter系に関して一つ一つ設定するのが面倒ということであれば、以下のように実装するといいと思います。

ex.)
services.yml

```
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        public: false
        arguments:
            - "@=service('service_container').parameters().all()"
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

twig extension作成

```
class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $params;
    public function __construct(array $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }
    public function getGlobals()
    {
        return ['params' => $this->params];
    }
}
```

twigでの利用方法

```
{{ params.myParam }}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
アクションでもテンプレートでも利用できるような値を取得するための
symfony設定ファイルの記述方法は用意されていないということでしょうか。
参考にして実装してみます。ありがとうございます。